# Will the recently-released AMD Epyc 4th Gen CPU support be added to the qemu package in 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, qemu

I noticed that Qemu has added a feature to support AMD Epyc 4th Genoa CPU.
However, upon checking the change log up to qemu1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.11 in the Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) Repo, I found that the patch to support AMD Epyc 4th Genoa CPU has not been applied.

I am writing to inquire if there are any plans to include this patch in future updates of the qemu package.

Here is the commit history in Qemu: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/166b1741884dd4fd7090b753cd7333868457a29b

Comment: Features like that are rarely, if ever, backported. Only bug/security fixes are. Personally, I wouldn't expect to see it in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Thank you!
That was helpful.